# Django dynamic filter based on variable (str)

Tags: python, django, filter

I am writing a function that can return table items based on a dynamically inserted model. So I need to refrain from using the model name in the function. Now I sometimes will have a many-to-many relationship with another model and want to select on that.

Say I have a projects = ManyToMany(Projects) field in my Files model. Now I can use:

```
filter(projects__in=[1])
```

to select for files related to projects with id 1, but I need the projects part of this filter to be dynamic, so I can use something like:

```
a_field = 'projects'
filter(a_field+'__in'=[1])
```

which obviously doesn't work. How should I do this?

Comment: I can see the similarity with the 'duplicate', but as a beginner, and related to many-to-many relationship, I think it's useful anyway.

Comment: The answers being exactly what I was looking for by the way!

Comment: No criticism at all :) the linked content of the dupe can be valuable for other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the `**kwargs` in Python: you construct a dictionary that maps string (the name of the parameters), to values, and then call the function with a dictionary with two asterisks, like:

```
a_field = 'projects'
params = {a_field+'__in': [1]}
filter(**params)
```

we of course need to construct the dictionary on a separate line:

```
a_field = 'projects'
filter(**{a_field+'__in': [1]})
```

If you thus have a dictionary like `{'foo': 'bar', 'qux': 14}`, then calling it with `foo(**{'foo': 'bar', 'qux': 14})` is equivalent to `foo(foo='bar', qux=14)`. This technique is not specific towards Django, but to Python. Python also has a way to do this with *positional* parameters: `foo(*[1, 'a', 4])` is equivalent to `foo(1, 'a', 4)`.